# Did Thanos go to this place at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Thor strikes Thanos with his new axe Stormbreaker and Thanos snaps his fingers inside the gauntlet, with all 6 Infinity Stones, does Thanos go inside the soul stone?

There is a scene with Gamora (younger) after the snap

> Gamora (younger): Did you do it?
>   Thanos: Yes.
>   Gamora (younger): What did it cost?
>   Thanos: Everything.

Is this scene taking place inside the soul stone?

Comment: Removed spoiler from the title.

Comment: I think its extremely hard to say for certain where Thanos is in the final scenes of the movie.  Its somewhat speculative that he's in the soul-stone.

Comment: I'm not even sure what makes you think that. Can you provide a little more context as to why you would even think that to be a possibility? Why would he "go inside the soul stone" and what does it mean to do so?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - The answer below is why. VTRO

Comment: If I could vote to reopen I’d do it.

Comment: @Mazura We're not taking answers to make questions actually make sense, we require questions to make sense on their own. So if you have any way to provide the question with a little more context, feel free to edit it accordingly. Though, it seems other people already did so anyway.

Comment: Yes - he was inside the Soul Stone reality, although whether he did it on purpose to see Gamora, or because he had a near-death experience, we don't know. The final scene, however, with him living on a farm, was NOT inside the Soul Stone - that was on some random planet he picked for his self-exile.

Answer (score 19):

**SPOILERS FOR INFINITY WAR**

According to the Rousso Brothers themselves (quoted [here](https://nerdist.com/infinity-war-soul-stone-world-russo-brothers-nerdist-news/) by Nerdist), the answer is

> yes. Thanos indeed went into the Soul World after his snap.

In the aforementioned interview, they said they tried to imply that this was the case (hence the orange tint of that scene), but the movie never says outright that this was the case.

Comment: >Q&A appearance by the Russo brothers in which they confirmed the theory that Thanos’ reunion with Gamora was not a hallucination or a vision. Instead, Thanos retreated into Soul World, the realm located within the Soul Stone that in the comics has been known to keep the souls of its victims. Thanos may have reluctantly killed Gamora to obtain the Soul Stone, but her spirit still resides within it.

Comment: >In Marvel’s comic book universe, Thanos killed Gamora when she turned against his plans of cosmic destruction, and her soul was kept in Soul World for several years after her death. During the Infinity Gauntlet storyline, Gamora, Pip the Troll, and Adam Warlock all managed to escape Soul World and get new bodies in the process.

Comment: Do you wan these comments added in the answer? You can [edit] your answer any time.

Comment: @NogShine I think my summary is enough. I don’t need a direct quotation from the article,  I don’t think.